# StringComparision.Ordinal is more accurate or IgnoreCase

Tags: c#, string

In a WinForms application that may be used in non-US-English environmnets too, I have a String.Equals(strA, strB) method and it is failing because I needed to do a a case-INsensitive comparision but by defdault is comparision is case-sensitive. Now to fix this what do you recommend is better?

- CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ?
- StringComparision.Ordinal ?
- StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase ?
  *ANY BETTER SUGGESTIONS?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to tell without you telling us what the strings represent.

Comment: ...and where they might come from.

Comment: @HansPassant : they are field names in a report that clinet creates. So they can name their field names whatever they like.

Comment: What culture are those field names? Are they computer generated? Are they actual field names from a database (which will have a fixed character set)?

Comment: I wouldn't change anything, tell them to use consistent capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. An `Ordinal` comparison does not respect the alphabetical order used by the culture.

But of course it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to do something that ignores the culture of the user, certainly there are other possibilities, including using the `InvariantCulture`.

**Addition:** Even if you are not sorting/ordering but only checking for "equal" versus "not equal", there may be a difference between `OrdinalIgnoreCase` and `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. For example, to an ordinal comparison, `"istanbul"` and `"Istanbul"` are equal, up to case. However, with a Turkish culture, they might not be equivalent, because the capital version of `'i'` is not `'I'` but `'İ'`. So the city would be `"İstanbul"`.

Comment: How's that relevant when you are only interested in equality?

Comment: mostly intrested in "case insestivie" comparision.

Comment: A report working on one computer but not another computer sounds like a really bad idea.